# Eth-brownie related problem- Error trying to deploy a contract

Tags: solidity, python, error, brownie

I’ve run into the following error while deploying a script. The script runs fine until the encode_and_supply function is called.

```bash
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/L2_aave_borrow.py", line 58, in main
    encode_and_supply(amount, account, lending_pool.address, weth)
  File "./scripts/L2_aave_borrow.py", line 164, in encode_and_supply
    encoder = L2Encoder.deploy({"from": account})
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 549, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'deploy'
```

**Relevant code**

```py
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account
from scripts.get_weth import get_weth
from brownie import L2Encoder, config, network, interface
```

```py
def main():
   account = get_account()
   erc20_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"]
   if network.show_active() in ["optimism-kovan"] or ["optimism-goerli"]:
       wethtx, weth = get_weth()
   lending_pool = get_lending_pool()
   approve_erc20(amount, lending_pool.address, erc20_address, account)
   encode_and_supply(amount, account, lending_pool.address, weth)
```

```py
def encode_and_supply(account, amount, lending_pool, weth):
   encoder = L2Encoder.deploy(lending_pool, {"from": account})
```

```py
def get_lending_pool():
    pool_addresses_provider = interface.IPoolAddressesProvider(
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["pool_addresses_provider"]
    )
    # Address collected
    lending_pool_address = pool_addresses_provider.getPool()
    lending_pool = interface.IL2Pool(lending_pool_address)
    return lending_pool
```

**L2Encoder.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: BUSL-1.1
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import { SafeCast } from "@aave/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/SafeCast.sol";
import { IPool } from "@aave/contracts/interfaces/IPool.sol";
import { DataTypes } from "@aave/contracts/protocol/libraries/types/DataTypes.sol";

/**
 * @title L2Encoder
 * @author Aave
 * @notice Helper contract to encode calldata, used to optimize calldata size in L2Pool for transaction cost reduction
 * only indented to help generate calldata for uses/frontends.
 */
contract L2Encoder {
  using SafeCast for uint256;
  IPool public immutable POOL;

  /**
   * @dev Constructor.
   * @param pool The address of the Pool contract
   */
  constructor(IPool pool) {
    POOL = pool;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes supply parameters from standard input to compact representation of 1 bytes32
   * @dev Without an onBehalfOf parameter as the compact calls to L2Pool will use msg.sender as onBehalfOf
   * @param asset The address of the underlying asset to supply
   * @param amount The amount to be supplied
   * @param referralCode referralCode Code used to register the integrator originating the operation, for potential rewards.
   *   0 if the action is executed directly by the user, without any middle-man
   * @return compact representation of supply parameters
   */
  function encodeSupplyParams(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint16 referralCode
  ) external view returns (bytes32) {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);

    uint16 assetId = data.id;
    uint128 shortenedAmount = amount.toUint128();
    bytes32 res;

    assembly {
      res := add(assetId, add(shl(16, shortenedAmount), shl(144, referralCode)))
    }
    return res;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes supplyWithPermit parameters from standard input to compact representation of 3 bytes32
   * @dev Without an onBehalfOf parameter as the compact calls to L2Pool will use msg.sender as onBehalfOf
   * @param asset The address of the underlying asset to supply
   * @param amount The amount to be supplied
   * @param referralCode referralCode Code used to register the integrator originating the operation, for potential rewards.
   *   0 if the action is executed directly by the user, without any middle-man
   * @param deadline The deadline timestamp that the permit is valid
   * @param permitV The V parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   * @param permitR The R parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   * @param permitS The S parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   * @return compact representation of supplyWithPermit parameters
   * @return The R parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   * @return The S parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   */
  function encodeSupplyWithPermitParams(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint16 referralCode,
    uint256 deadline,
    uint8 permitV,
    bytes32 permitR,
    bytes32 permitS
  )
    external
    view
    returns (
      bytes32,
      bytes32,
      bytes32
    )
  {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);

    uint16 assetId = data.id;
    uint128 shortenedAmount = amount.toUint128();
    uint32 shortenedDeadline = deadline.toUint32();

    bytes32 res;
    assembly {
      res := add(
        assetId,
        add(
          shl(16, shortenedAmount),
          add(
            shl(144, referralCode),
            add(shl(160, shortenedDeadline), shl(192, permitV))
          )
        )
      )
    }

    return (res, permitR, permitS);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes withdraw parameters from standard input to compact representation of 1 bytes32
   * @dev Without a to parameter as the compact calls to L2Pool will use msg.sender as to
   * @param asset The address of the underlying asset to withdraw
   * @param amount The underlying amount to be withdrawn
   * @return compact representation of withdraw parameters
   */
  function encodeWithdrawParams(address asset, uint256 amount)
    external
    view
    returns (bytes32)
  {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);

    uint16 assetId = data.id;
    uint128 shortenedAmount = amount == type(uint256).max
      ? type(uint128).max
      : amount.toUint128();

    bytes32 res;
    assembly {
      res := add(assetId, shl(16, shortenedAmount))
    }
    return res;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes borrow parameters from standard input to compact representation of 1 bytes32
   * @dev Without an onBehalfOf parameter as the compact calls to L2Pool will use msg.sender as onBehalfOf
   * @param asset The address of the underlying asset to borrow
   * @param amount The amount to be borrowed
   * @param interestRateMode The interest rate mode at which the user wants to borrow: 1 for Stable, 2 for Variable
   * @param referralCode The code used to register the integrator originating the operation, for potential rewards.
   *   0 if the action is executed directly by the user, without any middle-man
   * @return compact representation of withdraw parameters
   */
  function encodeBorrowParams(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 interestRateMode,
    uint16 referralCode
  ) external view returns (bytes32) {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);

    uint16 assetId = data.id;
    uint128 shortenedAmount = amount.toUint128();
    uint8 shortenedInterestRateMode = interestRateMode.toUint8();
    bytes32 res;
    assembly {
      res := add(
        assetId,
        add(
          shl(16, shortenedAmount),
          add(shl(144, shortenedInterestRateMode), shl(152, referralCode))
        )
      )
    }
    return res;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes repay parameters from standard input to compact representation of 1 bytes32
   * @dev Without an onBehalfOf parameter as the compact calls to L2Pool will use msg.sender as onBehalfOf
   * @param asset The address of the borrowed underlying asset previously borrowed
   * @param amount The amount to repay
   * - Send the value type(uint256).max in order to repay the whole debt for `asset` on the specific `interestRateMode`
   * @param interestRateMode The interest rate mode at of the debt the user wants to repay: 1 for Stable, 2 for Variable
   * @return compact representation of repay parameters
   */
  function encodeRepayParams(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 interestRateMode
  ) public view returns (bytes32) {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);

    uint16 assetId = data.id;
    uint128 shortenedAmount = amount == type(uint256).max
      ? type(uint128).max
      : amount.toUint128();
    uint8 shortenedInterestRateMode = interestRateMode.toUint8();

    bytes32 res;
    assembly {
      res := add(
        assetId,
        add(shl(16, shortenedAmount), shl(144, shortenedInterestRateMode))
      )
    }
    return res;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes repayWithPermit parameters from standard input to compact representation of 3 bytes32
   * @dev Without an onBehalfOf parameter as the compact calls to L2Pool will use msg.sender as onBehalfOf
   * @param asset The address of the borrowed underlying asset previously borrowed
   * @param amount The amount to repay
   * - Send the value type(uint256).max in order to repay the whole debt for `asset` on the specific `debtMode`
   * @param interestRateMode The interest rate mode at of the debt the user wants to repay: 1 for Stable, 2 for Variable
   * @param deadline The deadline timestamp that the permit is valid
   * @param permitV The V parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   * @param permitR The R parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   * @param permitS The S parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   * @return compact representation of repayWithPermit parameters
   * @return The R parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   * @return The S parameter of ERC712 permit sig
   */
  function encodeRepayWithPermitParams(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 interestRateMode,
    uint256 deadline,
    uint8 permitV,
    bytes32 permitR,
    bytes32 permitS
  )
    external
    view
    returns (
      bytes32,
      bytes32,
      bytes32
    )
  {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);

    uint16 assetId = data.id;
    uint128 shortenedAmount = amount == type(uint256).max
      ? type(uint128).max
      : amount.toUint128();
    uint8 shortenedInterestRateMode = interestRateMode.toUint8();
    uint32 shortenedDeadline = deadline.toUint32();

    bytes32 res;
    assembly {
      res := add(
        assetId,
        add(
          shl(16, shortenedAmount),
          add(
            shl(144, shortenedInterestRateMode),
            add(shl(152, shortenedDeadline), shl(184, permitV))
          )
        )
      )
    }
    return (res, permitR, permitS);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes repay with aToken parameters from standard input to compact representation of 1 bytes32
   * @param asset The address of the borrowed underlying asset previously borrowed
   * @param amount The amount to repay
   * - Send the value type(uint256).max in order to repay the whole debt for `asset` on the specific `debtMode`
   * @param interestRateMode The interest rate mode at of the debt the user wants to repay: 1 for Stable, 2 for Variable
   * @return compact representation of repay with aToken parameters
   */
  function encodeRepayWithATokensParams(
    address asset,
    uint256 amount,
    uint256 interestRateMode
  ) external view returns (bytes32) {
    return encodeRepayParams(asset, amount, interestRateMode);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes swap borrow rate mode parameters from standard input to compact representation of 1 bytes32
   * @param asset The address of the underlying asset borrowed
   * @param interestRateMode The current interest rate mode of the position being swapped: 1 for Stable, 2 for Variable
   * @return compact representation of swap borrow rate mode parameters
   */
  function encodeSwapBorrowRateMode(address asset, uint256 interestRateMode)
    external
    view
    returns (bytes32)
  {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);
    uint16 assetId = data.id;
    uint8 shortenedInterestRateMode = interestRateMode.toUint8();
    bytes32 res;
    assembly {
      res := add(assetId, shl(16, shortenedInterestRateMode))
    }
    return res;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes rebalance stable borrow rate parameters from standard input to compact representation of 1 bytes32
   * @param asset The address of the underlying asset borrowed
   * @param user The address of the user to be rebalanced
   * @return compact representation of rebalance stable borrow rate parameters
   */
  function encodeRebalanceStableBorrowRate(address asset, address user)
    external
    view
    returns (bytes32)
  {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);
    uint16 assetId = data.id;

    bytes32 res;
    assembly {
      res := add(assetId, shl(16, user))
    }
    return res;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes set user use reserve as collateral parameters from standard input to compact representation of 1 bytes32
   * @param asset The address of the underlying asset borrowed
   * @param useAsCollateral True if the user wants to use the supply as collateral, false otherwise
   * @return compact representation of set user use reserve as collateral parameters
   */
  function encodeSetUserUseReserveAsCollateral(
    address asset,
    bool useAsCollateral
  ) external view returns (bytes32) {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory data = POOL.getReserveData(asset);
    uint16 assetId = data.id;
    bytes32 res;
    assembly {
      res := add(assetId, shl(16, useAsCollateral))
    }
    return res;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Encodes liquidation call parameters from standard input to compact representation of 2 bytes32
   * @param collateralAsset The address of the underlying asset used as collateral, to receive as result of the liquidation
   * @param debtAsset The address of the underlying borrowed asset to be repaid with the liquidation
   * @param user The address of the borrower getting liquidated
   * @param debtToCover The debt amount of borrowed `asset` the liquidator wants to cover
   * @param receiveAToken True if the liquidators wants to receive the collateral aTokens, `false` if he wants
   * to receive the underlying collateral asset directly
   * @return First half ot compact representation of liquidation call parameters
   * @return Second half ot compact representation of liquidation call parameters
   */
  function encodeLiquidationCall(
    address collateralAsset,
    address debtAsset,
    address user,
    uint256 debtToCover,
    bool receiveAToken
  ) external view returns (bytes32, bytes32) {
    DataTypes.ReserveData memory collateralData = POOL.getReserveData(
      collateralAsset
    );
    uint16 collateralAssetId = collateralData.id;

    DataTypes.ReserveData memory debtData = POOL.getReserveData(debtAsset);
    uint16 debtAssetId = debtData.id;

    uint128 shortenedDebtToCover = debtToCover == type(uint256).max
      ? type(uint128).max
      : debtToCover.toUint128();

    bytes32 res1;
    bytes32 res2;

    assembly {
      res1 := add(add(collateralAssetId, shl(16, debtAssetId)), shl(32, user))
      res2 := add(shortenedDebtToCover, shl(128, receiveAToken))
    }
    return (res1, res2);
  }
}
```

**What I’ve tried**

Checked spelling is correct

Checked that I am importing from brownie correctly

Verified that the parameters to the encoder do not impact the error

Checked that the L2Encoder.sol is in the correct contracts folder

I’m not sure why L2Encoder is said to be an ‘int’ object. I tried to compare other brownie scripts with contract deployments and the method used seems to be the same. Any help would be much appreciated. Also, let me know if you need any more information

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your smart contract that you are trying to deploy?

Comment: Added now (L2Encoder.sol) @Emrah

Comment: this is a tough one